# Why "sort" behaves weirdly when "LANG" is not set?

Tags: linux, sorting

In my bash, "LANG" was set to "en_us.UTF-8", and "sort" works fine. But if I unset "LANG", then "sort" works weirdly. Even with "LC_ALL=C" or "LC_ALL=POSIX". Anyone know why "sort" doesn't work when "LANG" is not set?

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8

$ sort -t$'\t' -k1,3 -gr
-4.445905   1   0.965933
-4.445905   1   0.76126
-4.445905   1   0.74816
-4.445905   1   0.633251
-4.445905   1   0.596921
-4.445905   1   0.464271
-4.445905   1   0.406553
-4.445905   1   0.350968
-4.445905   1   0.307701
-4.445905   1   0.188411
-4.445905   1   0.0377354
-4.445905   1   0.0221152
-4.445905   -1  0.999663
-4.445905   -1  0.987287
-4.445905   -1  0.97882
-4.445905   -1  0.969835
-4.445905   -1  0.96705
-4.445905   -1  0.964982
-4.445905   -1  0.920791
-4.445905   -1  0.901001
-4.445905   -1  0.877351
-4.445905   -1  0.87702

-4.445905   -1  0.999663
-4.445905   -1  0.987287
-4.445905   -1  0.97882
-4.445905   -1  0.969835
-4.445905   -1  0.96705
-4.445905   1   0.965933
-4.445905   -1  0.964982
-4.445905   -1  0.920791
-4.445905   -1  0.901001
-4.445905   -1  0.877351
-4.445905   -1  0.87702
-4.445905   1   0.76126
-4.445905   1   0.74816
-4.445905   1   0.633251
-4.445905   1   0.596921
-4.445905   1   0.464271
-4.445905   1   0.406553
-4.445905   1   0.350968
-4.445905   1   0.307701
-4.445905   1   0.188411
-4.445905   1   0.0377354
-4.445905   1   0.0221152

$ unset LANG

$ sort -t$'\t' -k1,3 -gr
-4.445905   1   0.965933
-4.445905   1   0.76126
-4.445905   1   0.74816
-4.445905   1   0.633251
-4.445905   1   0.596921
-4.445905   1   0.464271
-4.445905   1   0.406553
-4.445905   1   0.350968
-4.445905   1   0.307701
-4.445905   1   0.188411
-4.445905   1   0.0377354
-4.445905   1   0.0221152
-4.445905   -1  0.999663
-4.445905   -1  0.987287
-4.445905   -1  0.97882
-4.445905   -1  0.969835
-4.445905   -1  0.96705
-4.445905   -1  0.964982
-4.445905   -1  0.920791
-4.445905   -1  0.901001
-4.445905   -1  0.877351
-4.445905   -1  0.87702

-4.445905   1   0.965933
-4.445905   1   0.76126
-4.445905   1   0.74816
-4.445905   1   0.633251
-4.445905   1   0.596921
-4.445905   1   0.464271
-4.445905   1   0.406553
-4.445905   1   0.350968
-4.445905   1   0.307701
-4.445905   1   0.188411
-4.445905   1   0.0377354
-4.445905   1   0.0221152
-4.445905   -1  0.999663
-4.445905   -1  0.987287
-4.445905   -1  0.97882
-4.445905   -1  0.969835
-4.445905   -1  0.96705
-4.445905   -1  0.964982
-4.445905   -1  0.920791
-4.445905   -1  0.901001
-4.445905   -1  0.877351
-4.445905   -1  0.87702

$ LC_ALL=POSIX sort -t$'\t' -k1,3 -gr
-4.445905   1   0.965933
-4.445905   1   0.76126
-4.445905   1   0.74816
-4.445905   1   0.633251
-4.445905   1   0.596921
-4.445905   1   0.464271
-4.445905   1   0.406553
-4.445905   1   0.350968
-4.445905   1   0.307701
-4.445905   1   0.188411
-4.445905   1   0.0377354
-4.445905   1   0.0221152
-4.445905   -1  0.999663
-4.445905   -1  0.987287
-4.445905   -1  0.97882
-4.445905   -1  0.969835
-4.445905   -1  0.96705
-4.445905   -1  0.964982
-4.445905   -1  0.920791
-4.445905   -1  0.901001
-4.445905   -1  0.877351
-4.445905   -1  0.87702

-4.445905   1   0.965933
-4.445905   1   0.76126
-4.445905   1   0.74816
-4.445905   1   0.633251
-4.445905   1   0.596921
-4.445905   1   0.464271
-4.445905   1   0.406553
-4.445905   1   0.350968
-4.445905   1   0.307701
-4.445905   1   0.188411
-4.445905   1   0.0377354
-4.445905   1   0.0221152
-4.445905   -1  0.999663
-4.445905   -1  0.987287
-4.445905   -1  0.97882
-4.445905   -1  0.969835
-4.445905   -1  0.96705
-4.445905   -1  0.964982
-4.445905   -1  0.920791
-4.445905   -1  0.901001
-4.445905   -1  0.877351
-4.445905   -1  0.87702
```

Comment: `"LANG" was set to "en_us.UTF-8", and "sort" works fine. But if I unset "LANG", then "sort" works weirdly.` Isn't it the exact opposite way around?

Comment: The first quoted sort does sort the first then the third column descending, which is expected. The later two "sort" after "unset LANG" doesn't sort the third column but instead sort the second column, which is unexpected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh i see the key is actually "from POS1 to POS2 inclusive", so "-k 1,3" means sort using key column1+column2+column3. n.m. you were correct, the later two sort actually did the right thing.

Comment: `-k1,3` means keys are from the first to the third column inclusively. If you want to ignore the second column, use `-k1 -k3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I didn't correctly understand the sort key option "-k". It is actually "from POS1 to POS2 inclusive", so "-k 1,3" means sort using key column1+column2+column3. Thus the later two "sort" are doing the correct thing, while the first is actually weird.